# Tar Multiple Files and Folders, and Specify Archive Structure

Tags: linux, tar

I'm working on a program update mechanism that basically uses a PHP script to find the latest versions of a set of files, and create a tar archive of these files.

So, the list of files being archived could be something like:

```
/updates/0.5.1/fileOne
/updates/0.5.1/fileTwo
/updates/0.5.2/folderOne/fileThree
/updates/0.5.3/folderOne/fileFour
```

What I'm trying to do is get all files in the list into a tar archive, with the caveat being that the directory structure *after* the version folder (e.g. 0.5.1/...) must be maintained. So, if all of those files were being put in an archive, the archive structure should be:

```
/fileOne
/fileTwo
/folderOne/fileThree
/folderOne/fileFour
```

I've tried simply using `tar cvf ...` with the full paths, but the resulting archive structure simply mirrors what I put in (/updates/...).

Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the pathname up into the version prefix and the rest. Then do:

```
tar rv -C "$prefix" -f "$tarfile" "$rest"
```

The `-C $prefix` option performs `cd $prefix` before archiving `$rest`, so you get just the pathname relative to that directory.

Use the `r` option instead of `c`, which appends to an existing archive rather than creating a new archive from scratch. This will allow you to loop through all the filenames, get each of their prefixes, and add them to the archive.

Answer (score 0):

How about just change dir to /updates and then for each directory (ie. for d in `ls`) change to that directory and append to the existing tar, and overwrite existing files in the tar?  ie. tar Auvf update.tar

That will work, right?